# Example of a compact topological space $M$ such that $\mathcal M_1(M)$ is not compact.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

It is well known that if $(M,\tau)$ is a compact Hausdorff topological space then (by [Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) + [Banach–Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem)) we have that the space 
$$\mathcal M_1(M) :=\left\{\mu;\ \mu\ \text{is a }\tau\text{-Borel probability measure on }M\right\} $$
is compact in the weak$^*$ topology, $\textit{i.e}.$ the topology generated by the basis of neighborhoods
$$V(\mu;f_1,\ldots,f_n;\varepsilon):=\left\{\lambda\in\mathcal M_1(M);\ \left|\int f_i\  \mathrm{d}\mu - \int f_i\  \mathrm{d}\lambda\right|<\varepsilon, \ \forall \ i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\right\}, $$
where $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in C^0_b(M)=\{g: M\to\mathbb R; \ g \text{ is a continuous bounded function}\}$.

> **My question:** Is there an example of a compact topological space $M$, such that $\mathcal M_1(M)$ is not compact in the weak${^*}$ topology?

I have searched online but I was not able to find any reference for this problem. Moreover, I have tried to construct a counter-example but I have failed miserably.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean if there is a *non-Hausdorff* compact topological space $M$ for which the weak-* compactness of the space of probability (Radon) measures on $M$ fails?

(by the way, continuous real-valued functions on a compact topological space are always bounded, even without the Hausdorff property)

Comment: I have only written continuous bounded function because  I was writting the general definition (if it was need for some reason). About the first question. When I say "Borel probability" I mean  a probability measure with respect to the $τ$ borel $σ$-algebra (the smallest $σ$-algebra that contains  $\tau$).

Comment: So, your underlying compact topological space $M$ is assumed to be Hausdorff, after all...?

Comment: No, $M$ is not Hausdorff. M is only compact. Like $Z_2$ with the topology $\{Z_2,∅\}$. There are some books that say $X$ is compact if $X$ is Hausdorff and if each of its open covers has a finite subcover. In my case, $X$ compact does not imply that $X$ is Hausdorff, it only means that each open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: This should be stated more explicitly in the question, then, since this is absolutely critical. I've posted an answer below where I go through the steps of the proof  in a bit more detail in the Hausdorff case, so it may become clearer in which of those the Hausdorff property of $M$ may be necessary. The answer is supposed to be updated in the future if a counterexample shows up, even if the bounty is expired or granted to someone else.

Comment: I've just found out that the Hausdorff property is indeed not needed - one just takes a suitable Hausdorff quotient of $M$. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is *no*: $\mathcal{M}_1(M)$ is *always* weak-* compact, because one can always in a certain sense "recover" the Hausdorff property of $M$ as far as the properties of the space of continous functions on $M$ are concerned.

First of all, just a small remark: continuous real-valued functions whose domain $M$ is compact are *always* bounded, regardless of $M$ being Hausdorff or not. The proof is classical: let $M$ be a compact (being Hausdorff is not needed) topological space, $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous, and $\{U_j\ |\ j\in J\}$ be an open cover of $f(M)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\{f^{-1}(U_j)\ |\ j\in J\}$ is an open cover of $M$. Since $M$ is compact, there is $I\subset J$ finite such that $\{f^{-1}(U_j)\ |\ j\in I\}$ is a subcover of $M$ and therefore $\{U_j\ |\ j\in I\}$ is a finite subcover of $\{U_j\ |\ j\in J\}$, hence $f(M)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is also compact. By the Heine-Borel theorem, $f(M)$ must be closed and bounded.

The (real) vector space $X=C(M,\mathbb{R})=C^0_b(M)$ of continuous ( $\Rightarrow$ bounded) (real valued) functions on a compact Hausdorff topological space $M$ is a Banach space when endowed with the supremum norm $\|f\|=\sup \{|f(x)|\ |\ x\in M \}$. The Hausdorff property of $M$ is also not needed to show completeness of $X$ in this norm - only the completeness of the codomain $\mathbb{R}$ is used. What is lost when one forfeits the Hausdorff property of $M$ is that one is no longer able to separate points of $M$ using continuous real-valued functions on it - more precisely, any (locally) compact Hausforff space is completely regular. However, the quotient space $\tilde{M}=M/\sim$ of $M$ modulo the equivalence relation $$x\sim y\Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)\text{ for all }f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\text{ continuous}$$ is Hausdorff (and compact) with the quotient topology, is canonically homeomorphic to $M$ if the latter happens to be Hausdorff already (since then one can separate the points of $M$ with $X$ and therefore the equivalence class $[x]\in\tilde{M}$ of $x\in M$ modulo $\sim$ $$[x]=\{x'\in M\ |\ x'\sim x\}$$ equals $\{x\}$ for all $x\in M$), and we may identify $X=C(M,\mathbb{R})$ with $C(\tilde{M},\mathbb{R})$ (**Edit:** this can be done even if $M$ is not compact and always yields a completely regular - but then not necessarily compact - $\tilde{M}$, see e.g. Theorem 3.9, pp. 40-41 of the book by L. Gilman and M. Jerison, *Rings of Continuous Functions*, van Nostrand, 1960, as pointed in [the answer to this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/360576/11211) made by the OP's author, also linked in his comments below). Moreover, due to the compactness of $M$ and Hausdorffness of $\tilde{M}$ the quotient map $$M\ni x\mapsto[x]\in\tilde{M}$$ is even closed.

(**Edit**) The Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem, on its turn, actually holds even if $M$ is not Hausdorff (without uniqueness in this case, as pointed in the comments below). One is able to identify the topological dual $X'$ of $X$ with the space of signed, finite Baire measures on $M$ (recall that the Baire $\sigma$-algebra on $M$ is the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{Ba}(M)$ generated by the zero level sets of elements of $X=C(M,\mathbb{R})$, which is contained in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{Bo}(M)$ of $M$) see e.g. Lemma 8.25, pp. 293-295 of the book by V. Komornik, *Lectures on Functional Analysis and the Lebesgue Integral*, Springer-Verlag, 2016. This lemma relies only on a version of Dini's lemma (see e.g. Lemma 8.24, pp. 293 of the same book) and does not require the Hausdorff property. One can go even further and identify $X'$ with the space of signed, finite (but no longer necessarily regular) *Borel* measures on $M$ thanks to the Corollary to Theorem II.2.6.1, pp. 227-228 of the book by K. Fuchssteiner and W. Lusky, *Convex Cones* (North-Holland, 1981), as also pointed in the [the answer to the aforementioned MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/360576/11211). More precisely, the results quoted above tell us how to recover a measure from a positive linear functional on $X$ (which, by the way, happens to be continous). This measure, as pointed in the comments, is not necessarily unique - consider e.g. Dirac measures concentrated on distinct points of $[x]$ for some $x\in M$ with $[x]\neq\{x\}$. This happens, for instance, for $x\in M$ with $\{x\}\neq\overline{\{x\}}$ if $M$ is not $T_1$.

Conversely, any signed, finite Borel (resp. Baire) measure $\mu$ on $M$ yields an element of $X'$ once we identify each such $\mu$ with the associated integral, seen as a (bounded, hence continous) linear functional on $X$: $$\mu(f)=\int_M fd\mu\ ,$$ so that for each Borel (resp. Baire) subset $A\subset M$ we have
$$\mu(A)=\int_M\mathbb{1}_A d\mu\ ,\quad\mathbb{1}_A(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & (x\in A) \\ 0 & (x\not\in A) \end{cases}\ .$$ As discussed above and in the comments below, this map is no longer injective if $M$ is not Hausdorff. However, one can still identify each element of $X'$ with a *unique* signed Radon measure on $\tilde{M}$ by the standard Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem, of course.

The weak-* topology on $X'$ is just the locally convex vector topology of pointwise convergence, determined by the seminorms $$\|\mu\|_f=|\mu(f)|=\left|\int_M fd\mu\right|\ ,\quad f\in X\ ,$$ hence a fundamental system of neighborhoods of zero in $X'$ in this topology is given by the neighborhoods $V(\mu;f_1,\ldots,f_n;\epsilon)$ you wrote above.

Finally, the Banach-Alaoglu theorem is an abstract result for Banach spaces which states that the unit ball $$B=\{\mu\in X'\ |\ \|\mu\|=\sup\{|\mu(f)|\ |\ \|f\|\leq 1\}\leq 1\}$$ in the norm topology of the topological dual $X'$ of a Banach space $X$ is compact in the weak-* topology. In our particular example, probability measures on $M$ are just the elements of $X'$ satisfying $$0\leq f\in X\Rightarrow\mu(f)\geq 0\ ,\,\mu(1)=1\ ,$$ the set $\mathcal{M}_1(M)$ of which is a *closed* subset of $X'$ in the weak-* topology (hence also in the norm topology of $X'$). Since $$|\mu(f)|\leq\mu(|f|)\leq\mu(1)=1$$ for all $f\in X$ with $\|f\|\leq 1$, $\mathcal{M}_1(M)$ is a (weak-* closed) subset of $B$, hence it must be weak-* compact as well.

Comment: I think he wants to know if the same holds without the assumption of $(M,\tau)$ being Hausdorff. It is clear from your proof that you have used the property of being Hausdorff a lot. Do you know if the same is true without using it?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. I do not know in which of the steps above (if any) the Hausdorff property of $M$ is necessary. This is not needed to show that continuous real valued functions on $M$ are bounded, though. In any case, the answer will need to be updated in the future if this turns out to be the case.

Comment: You use the Hausdorff property when you apply the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem.

Comment: Ok, but is this necessary? In other words, is there a non-Hausdorff counterexample to the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem? From there on, the arguments become abstract functional analysis, so I don't expect any further loopholes.

Comment: I know an easy example when the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem fails. For example $M =``[0,1]$ with two origins". $M$ will be compact and non-Hausdorff, it is easy to see that if $f$ is continuous then $f(0) = f(0')$. Therefore if $G:C^0(M)\to\mathbb{R}$ is the functional $G(f) = f(0)$, $G(f) = \int f \mathrm{d} \delta_0 =  \int f \mathrm{d} \delta_{0'}$. So  we lose uniqueness, but this does not matter at all. What I do not know is if we lose surjetive I think that $\lambda (A) = \inf\{G(f);\ f\text{ is continuous and bounded}, \ f\geq 0, \ f(A) =1\}$.It will satisfy $G=\lambda$

Comment: About your proof. How do you pullback the measure on $M/∼$ to $M$?

Comment: Yes, uniqueness for the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani representation theorem is lost without the Hausdorff property, it is no longer an isomorphism between $C(M,\mathbb{R})^*$ and the space of signed Radon measures on $M$, but it's still surjective. The pullback of a Radon measure on $\tilde{M}$ to $M$ can be performed as follows: if $\psi:M\rightarrow\tilde{M}$ is the quotient map, then we know it's a continuous, open surjection. One then simply sets $\psi^*\mu(A)=\mu(\psi(A))$ for any open set $A$. This doesn't always work for any continuous map, of course, but for this particular one it does.

Comment: I think that $ψ^∗μ(A)=μ(ψ(A))$ is not a measure, for instance. Imagine that you have $U$ and $V$ such that $ψ(U)\cap ψ(V)\neq \emptyset$, but $U\cap V = \emptyset$. Then it is not clear if $ψ^∗μ(U\cup V)  = ψ^∗μ(U) + ψ^∗μ(V).$ I do not know how to overcome this issue.  You have said that the identification of the signed finite measures still surjective in $C(M, \mathbb{R})^∗$, even in the non-Hausdorff case. But I was not able to find a reference with such a result (only assuming Hausdorff and locally compact), do you know any?

Comment: To make that a concrete example, if $M$ is the line with two origins $0$ and $0'$ then $\tilde{M} = \mathbb{R}$ (up to Homeomorphism). If the measure you get on $\tilde{M} = \mathbb{R}$ is $\delta_0$ then using the definition here $\psi^* \delta_0(\{0,0'\}) = \psi^* \delta_0(\{0\}) = \psi^* \delta_0(\{0'\}) = 1$ and so additivity clearly fails without further modification. [This mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/122719/87850) claims that the right additional information to use is a family of probability measures on the fibers of $\psi$ but I haven't verified the details of it.

Comment: (Continuing...) The resulting function $\psi^*\mu$ on the topology of $M$ is finite on $M$, zero on the empty subset and is countably subadditive, so it can be used to define an outer measure which then extends to a Borel measure on $M$ which has the same values on the topology of $M$ as $\psi^*\mu$. For the purposes of defining a linear functional on the space of continuous real valued functions on $M$, the ambiguity of this extension disappears since the set of points where a continuous real valued function does not vanish is always open and only $\psi^*\mu$ matters.

Comment: I'll add the above amendments to my answer when I can.

Comment: To be honest I am a bit confused about how we will use Caratheodory's theorem in order to get our measure on $M$. Which ring we will consider? (I am thinking to apply this theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem).  Could someone enlighten me? We have that $\psi^*\mu(A\sqcup B) = \psi^*\mu(A)  + \psi^*\mu(B)$ for open sets. But is this enough? Since the open sets are not a ring (or an algebra) I am not sure how to proceed. Maybe $\nu(A) = \inf\{\psi^*\mu(B);\ A\subset B\subset M\}$ will do the job, I will check it.

Comment: There is a different, weaker form of Carathéodory's extension theorem which is the following: one can begin with a family $\mathscr{C}$ of subsets of $M$ such that $\varnothing\in\mathscr{C}$ and any $A\subset M$ is contained in a countable union of members of $\mathscr{C}$, and a $[0,+\infty]$-valued function $\tau$ on $\mathscr{C}$ with $\tau(\varnothing)=0$.If we define $$\mu^*(A)=\inf\left\{\sum^\infty_{n=1}\tau(C_n)\ \Bigg|\ C_n\in\mathscr{C}\ ,\,\cup^\infty_{n=1}C_n\supset A\right\}\ ,\,A\subset M\ ,$$ then one can show that $\mu^*$ is a (not necessarily regular) outer measure.

Comment: (1/2) I deleted some comments last night because I realised their contents was incorrect right before I slept and didn't have time to write corrected versions. The main point I realised is that $\psi^* \mu$ **need not** be additive on the topology of $M$ and therefore definitely need not extend to a measure.

Comment: (2/2)  For example, consider $M = \{1,2,3\}$ equipped with the topology $\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$. Since the only open set containing $3$ is the whole space, $C(M)$ contains only constant functions. Therefore $\tilde{M} = \{p\}$ so $\mu$ is a scalar multiple of a dirac measure. Then $$\psi^* \delta_p(\{1,2\}) = \psi^*\delta_p(\{1\}) = \psi^* \delta_p(\{2\})$$ means additivity fails on the open sets in this case so $\psi^* \delta_p$ defined only on open sets cannot extend to a measure.

Comment: The most important point that needs to be proved is this: If you have a (finite) Borel measure $\mu_X$ on the Hausdorffication $X$ of $M$, is there a Borel measure $\mu_M$ on $M$ so that $\pi_*(\mu_M)=\mu_X$? This is the same question as whether or not every positive functional on $C(M)$ is induced by integration along a Borel measure.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360560/riesz-markov-kakutani-representation-theorem-for-compact-non-hausdorff-spaces/360576?noredirect=1#comment908498_360576 I think that this question on MO finishes all discussion and provide us a reference on how to do the extension that we want.

Comment: Interesting... however, I'd like to go through the details of that to see whether I could make my answer self-contained. I'll try to do that tomorrow.