# If a metric space $M$ is not compact then the space of probability measures $\mathcal M_1(M)$ is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, ergodic-theory

Let $M$ be a metric space. Then we define the space $\mathcal M_1(M)$ as the topological space

$$\mathcal M_1(M) :=\left\{\mu;\ \mu\ \text{is a } \text{Borel probability measure on }M\right\} $$
endowed with the weak$^*$ topology, $\textit{i.e}.$ the topology generated by the basis of neighborhoods
$$V(\mu;f_1,\ldots,f_n;\varepsilon):=\left\{\lambda\in\mathcal M_1(M);\ \left|\int f_i\  \mathrm{d}\mu - \int f_i\  \mathrm{d}\lambda\right|<\varepsilon, \ \forall \ i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\right\}, $$
where $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in C^0_b(M)=\{g: M\to\mathbb R; \ g \text{ is a continuous bounded function}\}$.

It is well known that if $M$ is a  separable metric space. Then $M$ is compact $\iff$ $\mathcal{M}_1(M)$ is compact. The proof of this fact relies on the result "$M$ is separable metric space then $\mathcal{M}_1(M)$ in the weak$^*$ topology is metrizable with  [Lévy–Prokhorov metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric)".

> **Question:** If $M$ is a non-compact metric space $\Rightarrow$ $\mathcal M_1(M)$ a non-compact topological space in the weak$^*$ topology?

---

### My conclusions so far

I think I have found a solution. Suppose that $M$ is a non-compact metric space then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, such that, $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not admit convergent subsequênce. Therefore, the set $S = \{x_1, \ldots, x_i,\ldots \}\subset M$ is closed, moreover all subsets of $S$ are  closed as well.

Now, consider the sequence $\{\delta_{x_i}\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathcal M_1(M)$ (where $\delta_p$ is the [Dirac measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure)), we will show that $\{\delta_{x_i}\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not admit convergence subnet, and this will imply that $\mathcal M_1(M)$ is not compact in the weak$^*$ topology (because we would be able to find a net that does not admit convergent subnet).

Suppose by *reductio ad absurdum* that there exist a [directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) $(\mathcal B, \preccurlyeq)$, an increasing function $\varphi: \mathcal B\to\mathbb{N}$, such that $\lim_{\beta}\varphi(\beta)=\infty$ (or cofinal porperty) and   $\mu\in\mathcal M_1(M)$ satisfying $$\lim_{\beta} \delta_{x_{\varphi(\beta)}} =\mu \in\mathcal M_1(M). $$

Let us, first of all, prove that $\mu(S)=1$. Let $f: M\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous bounded function such that $f(S)=\{1\}.$ Then, by the definition of weak$^*$ topology
$$1 = \lim_\beta \int f \ \mathrm d \delta_{x_{\varphi(\beta)}} =   \int f \ \mathrm d \mu.$$

Now consider the continuous (since $S$ is closed) bounded functions
\begin{align*}
g_n: M&\to\mathbb{[0,1]}\\
x&\mapsto \max\left\{ 1 - n \cdot d(x,S) ,0\right\},
\end{align*}
so  $g_n \to \mathbf{1}_S$ pointwiselly ( where $\mathbf{1}_S( S ) =\{1\}$  and $\mathbf{1}_S\left(M\setminus S\right) =\{0\}$) and each $g_n$ is a continuous bounded function such that $g_n(S)=\{1\}$. Note that $|g_i(x)|\leq g_1(x)$, $\forall$ $x\in M$. Thus, by dominated convergence theorem
$$1 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int g_n\ \mathrm{d}\mu  =  \int \lim_{n\to\infty}g_n\ \mathrm{d}\mu  =  \int \mathbf{1}_s\ \mathrm{d}\mu = \mu(S). $$

Now, let $i\in\mathbb{\mathbb N}$ and consider $S_i = \{1,\ldots,i\}$, by hypothesis $S_i$ and $S\setminus S_i$ are both closed, so there exists a continuous function $g: M\to [0,1]  $ such that $g(S_i) = \{1\}$ and $g(S \setminus S_i) = \{0\}$, since $\varphi(\beta)\to\infty$, there exists  $\beta_0\in\mathcal B$, $\beta_0\preccurlyeq \beta$, implies $i < \varphi(\beta)$. Hence,
$$0 = \lim_\beta \int g \ \mathrm d \delta_{x_{\varphi(\beta)}} =   \int g \ \mathrm d \mu \geq \mu(S_i).$$

Since $\mu(S) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(S_i) = 0$. Then $\mu\not\in \mathcal{M}_1(M)$, implying that $M$ is not compact.

Is the proof above correct? If so, why the vast majority of the books (at least all that I have checked) people just state the result for the case where $M$ is separable metric space?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am not quite sure whether you can conclude from $\mathrm{supp} \mu \subset S$ that $\mu(S)=1$, If you don't assume your metric space to be separable.

Comment: Or put differently (depending on your definition of the support of a measure), I am not sure that in a non-separable space your argument really shows that $\mathrm{supp}\mu \subset S$.

Comment: am i misreading? u said $M$ compact iff $M_1(M)$ compact. then u asked if $M$ is non-compact, is $M_1(M)$ compact.??

Comment: @mathworker21 maybe you are misreading. In this question, you have the hypothesis of $M$ being a metric space. My other question $M$ is only non-Hausdorff, therefore $M$ is not a metric space (this proof does not work you do not consider $M$ as a metric space).

Comment: @PhoemueX You have a good point. $\mu(S) = 1$ if the $M$ is Hausdorff and $\mu$ is Radon ($M$ separable would solve the problem as well). We only know that $\mu$ is outer regular (since $M$ is metric space and $\mu$ is a probability measure). I will think about an argument to fix this part. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @MatheusManzatto what "other question"?? u say here, that $M$ is a metric space

Comment: @mathworker21 Oh sorry. I thought that you were talking about this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673597/example-of-a-compact-topological-space-m-such-that-mathcal-m-1m-is-not-co?noredirect=1#comment7557585_3673597 (which does not make any sense). It is well known that if $M$ is a separable metric space then, $M$ compact $\iff$ $\mathcal M_1(M)$ is a compact. So if you suppose $M$ is a separable metric space, then we know the equivalence. If $\mathcal M_1(M)$ is compact, and $M$ is not separable then it is not clear if $M$ is compact.

Comment: @PhoemueX I think I was able to conclude that $\mu(S) =1$ by other methods.

Comment: I think that your revised argument is correct (and beautiful). I can't really tell you why most books only state this equivalence for separable metric spaces. My guess would be that one only likes to work with separable metric spaces in the first place, since otherwise many useful properties break down (e.g.: product sigma algebra of Borel sigma algebras is the Borel sigma algebra of the product, measures are automatically Radon, etc.)